# how to set multiple categories for a blog post in nodejs express and mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

I am beginner in backend and I am developing webservice for blog with express and mongoDb .

I want that every post of weblog to have multiple categories .

I have defined Post model like this

```
const mediaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
    }, 
    categories: [{
        required: true,
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
    }]
})
```

As you see Categories is Array of Object Ids

and this is category model

```
const catSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    title: { type: String, required: true },
});
```

the problem is that when I want to create a new post
and I send parameters like this

```
{
title : 'post title',
categories : [630fb5f122853b65d6ef1964 , 6310cba87d777bd35fe2dea4]
}
```

I get this error in Postman

[image]

so, How can I set multiple categories for a blog post?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue once where it was a type issue between ObjectId and String. So I used to get the string, convert it into objectId ( in the backend explicitly ), and store it.

Later, I just dropped that and mentioned schema type as the string itself so that I don't need to convert it into object id while storing them.

Comment: when you mentioned schema type as the string , didn't you have problem in populate it ?

Comment: No.
Because I designed the application in a way that those ids were not able to edit by the user manually.

Comment: And you can take that array stringified from the user interface, parse it in the backend and then try to store in the database. But at any cost, you have to again convert it into ObjectId and only then you can store it.